# Unable to find and install ImageMagick on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, imagemagick, centos8

I'm unable to install ImageMagick and ImageMagick-devel on a CentOS 8 64bit server. It should be as easy as:

> dnf install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel

When I do that I get:

> Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:53 ago on Wed 26 May 2021 11:48:26 AM CEST.
> All matches were filtered out by exclude filtering for argument: ImageMagick
> All matches were filtered out by exclude filtering for argument: ImageMagick-devel
> Error: Unable to find a match: ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel

I have already done:

> dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm -y

Which is installed and enabled. When I look in

> dnf repository-packages epel list

no ImageMagick package is listed.

How can I fix this and use dnf to install ImageMagick and ImageMagick-devel?

My repolist is:

- appstream: CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream
- baseos: CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS
- epel: Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
- epel-debuginfo: Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 - Debug
- epel-modular: Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
- epel-source: Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 - Source
- extras: CentOS Linux 8 - Extras
- litespeed: LiteSpeed Tech Repository for CentOS 8 - x86_64
- litespeed-update: LiteSpeed Tech Update Repository for CentOS 8 - x86_64
- powertools: CentOS Linux 8 - PowerTools
- remi-modular: Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
- remi-safe: Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
- yarn: Yarn Repository

Output of dnf repository-packages epel list | grep Image

- OpenImageIO.x86_64                                        2.1.20.0-1.el8                                  epel
- OpenImageIO-devel.x86_64                                  2.1.20.0-1.el8                                  epel
- OpenImageIO-iv.x86_64                                     2.1.20.0-1.el8                                  epel
- OpenImageIO-utils.x86_64                                  2.1.20.0-1.el8                                  epel
- libAfterImage.x86_64                                      1.20-22.el8                                     epel
- libAfterImage-apps.x86_64                                 1.20-22.el8                                     epel
- libAfterImage-devel.x86_64                                1.20-22.el8                                     epel
- perl-GD-SecurityImage.noarch                              1.75-4.el8                                      epel
- perl-Image-Base.noarch                                    1.17-15.el8                                     epel
- perl-Image-ExifTool.noarch                                12.16-3.el8                                     epel
- perl-Image-Info.noarch                                    1.41-8.el8                                      epel
- perl-Image-Size.noarch                                    3.300-16.el8                                    epel
- perl-Image-Xbm.noarch                                     1.10-11.el8                                     epel
- perl-Image-Xpm.noarch                                     1.13-10.el8                                     epel

Output of dnf repository-packages epel list | grep image

- freeimage.x86_64                                          3.17.0-4.el8                                    epel
- freeimage-devel.x86_64                                    3.17.0-4.el8                                    epel
- freeimage-plus.x86_64                                     3.17.0-4.el8                                    epel
- freeimage-plus-devel.x86_64                               3.17.0-4.el8                                    epel
- kf5-kimageformats.x86_64                                  5.68.0-1.el8                                    epel
- kiwi-systemdeps-disk-images.x86_64                        9.23.34-1.el8                                   epel
- kiwi-systemdeps-image-validation.x86_64                   9.23.34-1.el8                                   epel
- libimagequant.x86_64                                      2.12.5-1.el8                                    epel
- libimagequant-devel.x86_64                                2.12.5-1.el8                                    epel
- python3-openimageio.x86_64                                2.1.20.0-1.el8                                  epel
- qt5-qtimageformats-doc.noarch                             5.12.3-1.el8                                    epel
- root-graf-asimage.x86_64                                  6.22.08-1.el8                                   epel

Comment: `epel` is in your repolist.  What does `dnf repository-packages epel list` show? Did you try `dnf clean all`  then `dnf makecache`?

Comment: Yes I have run dnf clean all and dnf makecache. I have added the output of dnf repository-pacakges epel list to my original post. I added a grep command, to narrow the list a bit.

Comment: I have found the culprit. I am doing a server migration and in my /etc/dnf/dnf.conf I had exclude=mysql*,ImageMagick*,GraphicsMagick* . I have removed the excludes and I can now find ImageMagick. I feel so stupid. Thank you for all your help! @GoinOff

Comment: I've shot myself in the foot like that many times..Glad you found the problem. I usually say "D'ohhhh"

Answer (score 3):

It's kinda lame in CentOS 8 how by default, many needed repos are not enabled by default and packages are spread out now among the different repos making life more of a pain in the a$$ instead of easier..

ImageMagick packages are in the epel repo

```
[root@test35 map]# repoquery -i ImageMagick-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:23:13 ago on Wed 26 May 2021 04:52:14 AM PDT.
Name         : ImageMagick-devel
Version      : 6.9.10.86
Release      : 1.el8
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 126 k
Source       : ImageMagick-6.9.10.86-1.el8.src.rpm
Repository   : epel
Summary      : Library links and header files for ImageMagick app development
URL          : http://www.imagemagick.org/
License      : ImageMagick
Description  : ImageMagick-devel contains the library links and header files
             : you'll need to develop ImageMagick applications. ImageMagick is
             : an image manipulation program.
             :
             : If you want to create applications that will use ImageMagick code
             : or APIs, you need to install ImageMagick-devel as well as
             : ImageMagick. You do not need to install it if you just want to
             : use ImageMagick, however.
```

To enable popular repos containing many needed packages for a typical server, run the following

```
yum install epel-release javapackages-tools
yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

rebuild yum or dnf:

```
yum clean all
yum makecache
yum repolist

[root@localhost ~]# yum repolist
                     repo id            repo name
                     appstream          CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream
                     baseos             CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS
                     epel               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
                     epel-modular       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
                     extras             CentOS Linux 8 - Extras
                     powertools         CentOS Linux 8 - PowerTools

                List of rpms in epel where ImageMagick-devel is located:

                    yum repo-pkgs epel list

[root@test35 map]# dnf clean all
49 files removed
[root@test35 map]# dnf makecache
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                      3.9 MB/s | 6.3 MB     00:01
CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS                         1.2 MB/s | 2.3 MB     00:01
CentOS Linux 8 - Extras                          27 kB/s | 9.6 kB     00:00
CentOS Linux 8 - PowerTools                     1.6 MB/s | 2.0 MB     00:01
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - 453 kB/s | 610 kB     00:01
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64  4.2 MB/s | 9.4 MB     00:02
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Wed 26 May 2021 06:09:19 AM PDT.
Metadata cache created.

[root@test35 map]# dnf repository-packages epel list|grep ImageMagick
ImageMagick.x86_64                                        6.9.10.86-1.el8                                 epel
ImageMagick-c++.x86_64                                    6.9.10.86-1.el8                                 epel
ImageMagick-c++-devel.x86_64                              6.9.10.86-1.el8                                 epel
ImageMagick-devel.x86_64                                  6.9.10.86-1.el8                                 epel
ImageMagick-doc.x86_64                                    6.9.10.86-1.el8                                 epel
ImageMagick-libs.x86_64                                   6.9.10.86-1.el8                                 epel
ImageMagick-perl.x86_64                                   6.9.10.86-1.el8
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I do not have repoquery installed and dnf install repoquery, isn't working (same problem as with ImageMagick it seems). I did all the other steps you listed. Unfortunately the 'dnf repository-packages epel list|grep ImageMagick' returns nothing.

Comment: you can install `yum install yum-utils` for repoquery.  What does `dnf repolist` show you?

Comment: You should see `epel` and `epel-modular` in your repolist.

Comment: You can also rebuild by running `dnf clean all`,`dnf makecache`,

Comment: Thank you the additional commands. I managed to install repoquery. When I run that command it returns nothing. I ran dnf clean all and dnf makecache. I added my current repolist to my original post.

Comment: Yes, add your current repo list to your post `dnd repolist`

Comment: My CentOS version - CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011

Comment: I am using CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011 also